# Eliminar bordes verticales de todo un TR en una tabla, sin combinar celdas

Tags: html5, css3, tablas

Quería ver si me podían ayudar con algo de HTML5/CSS3. Hice una tabla con columnas y filas. Después les apliqué a los `TD` un `padding:0` y la propiedad `border-collapse: collapse` (+ ese valor), para que la tabla quede dividida en cuadrículas con un borde en común para cada celda.

Ahora estoy tratando de hacer que un `TR` no tenga bordes verticales (cuando le comente lo de los colores van a darse cuenta por qué): no me sirve combinar las celdas porque yo necesito que su contenido quede alineado con el contenido de las demás celdas de su misma columna.

Puedo aplicarle CSS en línea al `TR` aplicándole un color de fondo (negro en este caso) y un color de fuente (blanco), pero ese color blanco también se le aplica a los bordes; entonces trato de aplicarle a dicho `TR` la propiedad + el valor `border: none`, pero no me lo toma, tampoco si quiero aplicarle a los bordes (`border-color`) el mismo color que tiene el fondo (negro).

Lo que termino haciendo es aplicarle a cada `TD` de ese `TR` la propiedad + el valor `border: none`. Eso sí me funciona pero tengo que hacerlo para cada uno de los `TD`: en este caso no son muchos, pero si lo fueran no sería muy práctico. Les comparto el código de la tabla y el CSS que le apliqué desde una hoja de estilos.

```css
table {
  border: solid;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
}

td, th {
  border: solid;
  padding: 0;
}

th {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th colspan="7"><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">Farmacias de Turno</span><br>Noviembre 2022</th>
  <tr style="background-color: black; color: white;">
    <td style="border:none;">D</td>
    <td style="border:none;">L</td>
    <td style="border:none;">M</td>
    <td style="border:none;">M</td>
    <td style="border:none;">J</td>
    <td style="border:none;">V</td>
    <td style="border:none;">S</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>D4</td>
    <td>E5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>F6</td>
    <td>G7</td>
    <td>H8</td>
    <td>I9</td>
    <td>A10</td>
    <td>B11</td>
    <td>C12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A13</td>
    <td>E14</td>
    <td>F15</td>
    <td>G16</td>
    <td>H17</td>
    <td>I18</td>
    <td>A19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B20</td>
    <td>C21</td>
    <td>D22</td>
    <td>E23</td>
    <td>F24</td>
    <td>G25</td>
    <td>H26</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>I27</td>
    <td>A28</td>
    <td>B29</td>
    <td>C30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Espero se entienda y puedan ayudarme. Muchas gracias.

Comment: En que TR no quieres bordes ??? Una imagen ejemplo explicaria mas

Comment: En el TR que tiene los días de la semana: el primero de la tabla. Perdón si no se entiende, me acabo de registrar en esta página pero si la había visitado algunas veces. No quise poner una imagen porque me pareció que no se iba a entender en comparación de si la página daba la posibilidad de ejecutar el código que escribí junto con la pregunta. pero creo que no aparece esa opción porque no escribí la estructura del html.

Comment: Mejor con imagen btw, al menos para CSS. El tr de los dias, es el de lunes... domingo, no ?? y que bordes quieres quitarle ?

Comment: Disculpas otra vez. Ahí vi que sí se puede ejecutar el código para que muestre la tabla. Así como la muestra es como yo quiero que se vea: que la fila de los días de la semana tenga todo el fondo negro y que no haya bordes de otro color entre sus celdas (quedaban del mismo color que la fuente). El problema que tengo es que para que se vea así tuve que ir por cada TD de ese TR, especificando que no quería que tengan bordes. Buscaba algo más general, que solamente lo tenga que escribir una vez, como cuando configuré el color de fuente y de fondo a TD pero aplicándoselo al TR.

Comment: Sisi esa misma es la de los días

Comment: Si asi como se vee actualmente, es como la quieres, no la pongas de ese modo. Editala, y coloca "el problema", el error es lo que se necesita ver. Puedes tener mas info de este tema en [mre]

Comment: Es que mi problema sería ese. No que no lo puedo hacer, sino que imagino que hay una manera más simplificada de hacerlo. No tengo mucho conocimiento pero calculo que debe haber otra manera, porque si fuesen muchas filas (más no todas) las de una tabla a la que le quisiese hacer eso sería Demasiado engorroso. Lo planteo como la posibilidad de hacer 3 archivos html con la misma estética pero en vez de usar una hoja de estilos, les aplicara las mismas propiedades pero en línea: a cada elemento y a cada documento html.

Comment: Como dije, edita tu respuesta a como es el problema (dado que actualmente "esta solucionado")... supongo que el codigo es el mismo sin los border none esos...}

Comment: Ok. Ahora entiendo. Tendría que cambiar prácticamente toda la consulta o directamente hacer una nueva. En un momento la vuelvo a postear. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me adelanto a tu edición para la modificación que creo que buscas...

He quitado esos `border: none;` de los TR mencionados, y si, queda un blanco horrendo...

Todo esto se corrige aplicando una clase al TR que quieres acceder, y tocando los TD que sean hijos de este. Ahí podes aplicarle el estilo que quieras.

```css
table {
  border: solid;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
}

td, th {
  border: solid;
  padding: 0;
}

th {
  background-color: grey;
}

.sinBordes td{ /* Nueva clase */
  border: none; /* Mismo estilo */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th colspan="7">
    <span style="font-size: 1.2em;">
      Farmacias de Turno
    </span>
    <br>
    Noviembre 2022
  </th>
  <tr style="background-color: black; color: white;" class="sinBordes">
    <td>D</td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>J</td>
    <td>V</td>
    <td>S</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>D4</td>
    <td>E5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>F6</td>
    <td>G7</td>
    <td>H8</td>
    <td>I9</td>
    <td>A10</td>
    <td>B11</td>
    <td>C12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A13</td>
    <td>E14</td>
    <td>F15</td>
    <td>G16</td>
    <td>H17</td>
    <td>I18</td>
    <td>A19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B20</td>
    <td>C21</td>
    <td>D22</td>
    <td>E23</td>
    <td>F24</td>
    <td>G25</td>
    <td>H26</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>I27</td>
    <td>A28</td>
    <td>B29</td>
    <td>C30</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah si. Calculaba que esa iba a ser una forma, porque vi ese sistema varias veces. Pasa que como no estoy tan familiarizado con eso de las clases. Gracias

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta si es que te ha servido y un +1 para mi ego XD